# Convert pandas column of type list to dict

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

Pandas column of length *n* is of type *list*.

```
df['size'][0] = [{'Name': 'Total', 'Value': 50, 'Unit': 'Units'}]

type(df['Size'][0]) 
list
```

I'd like to convert the list to a dictionary. i.e `type(df['Size'][0]) dict`.

```
{'Name': 'Total', 
 'Value': 50, 
 'Unit': 'Units'}
```

For context, I am trying to parse out the dictionary into multiple columns.

```
   # Unpack Size

   for i, row in df.iterrows():

       if type(row['Size'][i]) is dict:

           dict_obj = row['Size'][i]

           for key, val in dict_obj.items():

                if key == 'Name':
                   df.loc[index, 'Size_Name'] = val

                if key == 'Value':
                   df.loc[index, 'Size_Value'] = val

                if key == 'Unit':
                   df.loc[index, 'Size_Unit'] = val
```

Comment: Have you tried this ... df['Size'][0] = df['Size'][0][0]?

Comment: Is it always list of one dictionary or can there be many many dictionaries i.e `df['size'][x] = [{...},{...},{...}]`?

Comment: @Ch3steR Not always, there can be n number of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there can be n number of dictionaries.

When you have arbitary number of dictionaries in list use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'size':[[{'a':1},{'b':1}],[{'a':2}],[{'c':2},{'d':2},{'e':4}]]})

df
                             size
0            [{'a': 1}, {'b': 1}]
1                      [{'a': 2}]
2  [{'c': 2}, {'d': 2}, {'e': 4}]

df.explode('size')

       size
0  {'a': 1}
0  {'b': 1}
1  {'a': 2}
2  {'c': 2}
2  {'d': 2}
2  {'e': 4}
```

If it's always list of one dictionary i.e `df['size'][x] = [{...}]` use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain

df['size'] = list(chain.from_iterable(df['size']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
df['size'][0] = [{'Name': 'Total', 'Value': 50, 'Unit': 'Units'}]

type(df['Size'][0]) 
list
```

you should use:

```
type(df['Size'][0][0]) 
dict
```

And if you have several dictionaries in the list, increase the last index to get access to the rest of them.